# Correct preposition with "to be jealous"

Tags: prepositions

Let's say Alice sees her boyfriend Bob with Charlotte, another girl. Now, I know the correct usage is "Alice is jealous **of** Bob". My question is how to connect this predicate (be jealous) to Charlotte. That is:

Alice is jealous [of Bob] ___ Charlotte.

What preposition should come before Charlotte? If there is such a preposition, can I leave the part between the square brackets (of Bob) out?

Or how can I otherwise express this idea with and without including Bob in the equation?

Comment: Seems to me that Alice is jealous of Charlotte.  (But then I usually assume "straight" until informed otherwise.)

Comment: This is an interesting question. I am really frustrated with this word because I can not find any usage examples. It is obvious, jealousy takes three: a jealous person, someone the person is jealous of, and the third person who gives reason for jealousy. But the English language seems to consider only two people in the case of jealousy.

Comment: @javaNoobs - Jealousy does not require a third party.  Bob can be jealous of Frank because Frank has a fancier motorcycle.

Comment: @Hot Licks - in case of things, no it does not, that is right. In this case the usage is 'Bob is jealous of Frank for his fancy chopper' (fancy is a word for choppers, not sport bikes). But in case of human sexual relationship there is always a third party, a man or a woman, with the only exception when a partner masturbates.

Comment: But the net is that "jealousy" is between the person who has the emotion, and the person or object that the first person envies.  "Jealousy" does not refer to the reason for the envy.  Especially in the case of the proverbial lover's triangle this is inconvenient, in that all parties cannot be referred to using a single verb, but that's the way it is.  (And I don't offhand know of another term that allows specifying all three parties or even a separate one which will concisely identify the otherwise omitted party.)

Comment: @Hot Licks - sentence structure provides for subject, predicate, object, indirect object, complement. Even the most basic sentence may contain subject, predicate, and object. For example 'Give' implies two members as in 'Give it to me'. There are a lot of verbs that imply at least subject and object.

Comment: @javaNoobs - But how do you refer to three parties?

Comment: @Hot Licks - grammatically, I don't, in my comments. Because in grammar 'I' am party 1,  'you' are party 2, and 'he|she'  is party 3. But in the situation there are 3 parties. If Bob was jealous of Frank because his Charlotte flirted with Frank and he punched him in the face, the legal prosecution will consider 3 parties.

Comment: @javaNoobs - And there's no English verb to define that relationship.

Comment: @Hot Licks - I am new to ELU and I have noticed that people, especially non-native speakers, tend to seek for a magic one word that describes everything. Sometimes this is because they have that word in their native language and want a literal translation.

Comment: "Alice is jealous of Bob  *for* Charlotte." -- 'because of' Cf: "Alice *wouldn't have been* jealous of Bob  *but for* Charlotte."

Comment: @Kris - So Bob has taken Charlotte away from Alice??

Comment: @Kris - Why on earth would Alice be jealous for Charlotte? She does not need her and she hates her. Alice loves Bob and she is jealous of Bob towards Charlotte.

Comment: @javaNoobs *for* in the sense of 'because of' -- pl see my comment again.

Comment: I find 'Alice is jealous of Bob' wrong because Alice is in a relationship already with him and so would be jealous of Charlotte as she(Charlotte) is getting the love which Alice deserves. Why is Alice jealous of Bob? It's not like she envies the social skills of her boyfriend where he is able to befriend people like Charlotte easily. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The correct construct is "Alice is jealous of Bob and Charlotte". Jealousy is defined by Merriam-Webster's dictionary as, "an unhappy or angry feeling of wanting to have what someone else has," or, "an unhappy or angry feeling caused by the belief that someone you love (such as your husband or wife) likes or is liked by someone else." (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jealousy)

Therefore, Alice is jealous of Bob for being loved by Charlotte, and Alice is jealous of Charlotte for loving Bob.

Comment: Hi @Ben, welcome to ELU. I've removed your reference to another user, as it wasn't clear which post/comment it was related to. Your answer can (and should) stands alone without referencing other users' posts.

Comment: I had referenced Little Eva because it was the same wording that was used in his comment on javaNoobs' Answer, but if you feel it's unnecessary I'll leave it out. Thanks AndyT.

Answer (score 0):

If you believe the prophet Ezekiel, it is "jealous against":

> And I will set my jealousy against thee, and they shall deal furiously with thee
>   — Ezekiel 23:25

Comment: This example is too ancient to rely on for modern usage :-)

Comment: Yeah, a lot of people say that about the Bible.  "My friend Weird Howard tells me he got a new job.  He is selling Bibles.  I say, 'Weird Howard, Bibles are free.' He says, 'These are *custom* Bibles. For $20 extra, I'll take out any two Commandments.' So now I can commit adultery on Sundays."

Answer (score 0):

A problem with 'jealous' is that it does not only mean… (as in your question)

what it should – 'not wanting other people to take away from you what or who you *have*'

but also

what it should not – 'wanting to take away from other people what or who they *have*'

which is unambiguously rendered by 'envious'.

But that does not address your question…

So, here is: if you are 'jealous of what you have', **it goes without saying** that you want to protect it **from anyone and everyone**. If this goes without saying, then a preposition to introduce what need not be mentioned is unnecessary!

Answer (score 0):

Alice is jealous of Charlotte.

You are right, you don't need "of Bob".

The [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jealous) says

> Fearful or wary of losing one's position or situation to someone else, especially in a sexual relationship: *Her new boyfriend was jealous of her male friends.*

Answer (score -2):

The usage examples I have found contain 'of' in all cases:

- jealous of my wife's friends
- jealous of my husband's co-workers
- jealous of his wife

These examples make me think the correct usage is:

> Alice is jealous **of** Bob **of** Charlotte.

An example, 'Comment of the Week: I’m Jealous of My Wife’s Friends' on [emandlo.com](http://www.emandlo.com/2013/08/comment-of-the-week-im-jealous-of-my-wifes-friends/)

> “Your Call: Why Is My Husband Jealous of My Female Friendships?”

Here is another example on [mentalhelp.net](https://www.mentalhelp.net/advice/husband-jealous-of-my-friends-and-family/)

> "My husband and I have been married for 6+ years. I would consider us
>   to be one of the happiest couples I know. With that said, every 3-4
>   months my husband displays signs of jealousy (**of my family and girl
>   friends**) and lashes out at me. He tells me that as a wife I should put
>   him first. In my eyes I always have and always will."

Either example deals with the third party to jealousy, the reason of jealousy (Charlotte) rather than an object of jealousy (Bob) in your given example.

Comment: Alice is jealous of Bob and Charlotte.

Comment: @Little Eva - this sounds very elegant and clear, why don't you make this an answer?

Comment: Because I gave it to thou.

Comment: @Little Eva - but there is one little disadvantage with dropping a preposition: it is not always clear whom exactly Alice loves or hates

Comment: I believe Alice is envious of Bob & Charlotte's relationship. She has come to realize that their friendship has qualities missing from her and Bob's relationship.

Comment: @Little Eva - That is probably a native English speaker way of thinking. In some language, for example, Ukrainian or Russian we use this construct, 'Is  jealous of someone for someone' in most cases.

Comment: I "get" that, javaNoobs.